# mount LVM2 dump or extract files

Tags: lvm, mount, dump, data-extraction, kpartx

I have a dump of a filesystem. I dont know how it was created. I want to extract all the files and the filestructure.

`file dump.bin` says it is a *LVM2 PV (Linux Logical Volume Manager)* file and prints a UUID and the size.
I tried to use kpartx like this: `sudo kpartx -a -v dump.bin` but there are no partitions in `/dev/mapper/` afterwards.

When I `cat` the file, it starts with `imageUSB` and is followed with content like this:

```
uarea {
id = "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
seqno = 1
format = "lvm2"
status = ["RESIZEABLE", "READ", "WRITE"]
flags = []
extent_size = 2048
max_lv = 0
max_pv = 0
metadata_copies = 0

physical_volumes {

pv0 {
id = "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
device = "/dev/sda"

status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
flags = []
dev_size = xxxx
pe_start = xxxx
pe_count = xxxx
}
}


}
# Generated by LVM2 version ....
```

How can I mount the filesystem or extract all files and the filestructure?

I already tried to use binwalk to extract all files, but it crashes because no memory is left, I guess because the dump is too big.